# Method file does not exist. laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am following [DevsBrasil' Laravel tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4cWAwUGAvc), trying to crop user image.

and give this error 'Method file does not exist. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\event\app\views\dashboard\users\edit.blade.php)'

Controller:

```
    public function editUsers($userID) {

    $user = Sentry::findUserById($userID);

    $data = array();
    $data['image'] = Session::get('img');
    $data['modal'] = (Session::get('modal') == null ? 'false' : 'true');

    $group_p = $user->getGroups();

    $groups_p = [];
    foreach (Sentry::findAllGroups() as $group) {
        $groups_p [$group->id] = $group->name; 
    }

    return View::make('dashboard.users.edit')
    ->with('user',$user)
    ->with('group_p',$group_p)
    ->with('groups_p',$groups_p)
    ->with('data',$data);

}

public function updateUsers($userID) {

    $user = Sentry::findUserById($userID);


    return View::make('dashboard.users.edit')
    ->with('user',$user);
}

public function UploadImg($userID)
{
    if (Input::hasFile('image')) {

    $user = Sentry::findUserById($userID);

    $image_name = $image->getClientOriginalName();

    $image = Input::file('image');
            $filename  = $user->username . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $path = public_path('img/users/' . $filename);
            $int_image = Image::make($image->getRealPath());

            $int_image->resize(568,null, function($constraint){
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });

            $int_image->save($path);
            $user->image = 'img/users/'.$filename;

            Session::put('modal','ture');
    }else{
    }

        return Redirect::back();

}

public function CropImg()
{
        return Redirect::back();
}
```

Routes

```
    Route::get('/admin.dashboard/users', [
    'as'    => 'users_get',
    'uses'  => 'AuthController@getUsers'
    ]);

Route::get('/admin.dashboard/users/edit/{userID}', [
    'as'    => 'edit_user_form_get',
    'uses'  => 'AuthController@editUsers'
    ]);

Route::put('/', [
    'as'    => 'update_user_form_get',
    'uses'  => 'AuthController@updateUsers'
    ]);

Route::post('/admin.dashboard/users/update-user-image/{userID}', [
    'as'    => 'update_user_image_post',
    'uses'  => 'AuthController@UploadImg'
    ]);

Route::post('/admin.dashboard/users/crop-user-image', [
    'as'    => 'crop_user_image_post',
    'uses'  => 'AuthController@CropImg'
    ]);
```

Edit View :
the two methods is in a controller - above -

```
    @extends('dashboard.mainlayout')
@section('title')
Edit {{$user->first_name}} Acc
@stop
@section('scripts_header')

@stop
@section('scripts_footer')

<script>
    var modal;
    if ($('#modal').val() == 'ture' ) {
        modal = true;
    }else{
        modal = false;
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#crop').Jcrop({
            aspectRatio: 1,
            onSelect: atualizaCoordenadas
        });
        $('#img_modal').modal({show: modal});
    });

    function atualizaCoordenadas(c){
        $('#x').val(c.x);
        $('#y').val(c.y);
        $('#w').val(c.w);
        $('#h').val(c.h);
    }

    function checkCoords(){
        if (parseInt($('#w').val())) return true;
        alert('Error');
        return false;
    }

</script>
@stop
@section('content')
                      <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="bootbox modal fade in" id="img_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: block;">
                           <div class="modal-dialog">
                              <div class="modal-content">
                                 <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Crop Image</h4>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="modal-body">
                                    {{Form::open(array('route' => 'crop_user_image_post', 'onsubmit' => 'return checkCoords' ,'class'=>'form-horizontal'))}}
                                    {{HTML::image($data['image'], '' , ['id' => 'crop'] )}}
                                    <input type="hidden" id="src" name="src" value="{{ $data['image'] }}" >
                                    <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
                                    <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
                                    <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
                                    <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button data-bb-handler="Done" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success!</button>
                                 </div>
                                 {{ Form::close() }}
                              </div>
                           </div>


                           {{Form::open(array('route' => 'update_user_image_post', 'method' => 'post','files'=>'true','class'=>'form-horizontal') , $user->id)}}
                                       {{ HTML::image($user->img, $user->username, array('class' => 'img-circle' )) }}
                                       {{HTML::file('image')}}
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload Image <i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                           {{ Form::close() }}


                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- // Tab content END -->

@stop
```

Where's an error ??
what's i have to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{HTML::file('image')}}
```

I don't believe there's any `file` method on the `HTML` alias.  That class is an alias to the `HTML` facade (`Illuminate\Support\Facades\HTML`) which is just a shortcut into the IoC container for the class `Illuminate\Html\HtmlBuilder`.  Looking inside that class, I see no mention of a `file` method.

Comment: no problem. I tried going through that video tutorial, but I don't speak that language :)

Answer (score 1):

It is probably complainting about

```
{{HTML::file('image')}}
```

Because there is no file method in the HTMLBuilder class.